# Azure standard to premium, and back

Tags: azure

I see a new premium tier for Azure App Service that may help one of my multi-tenant apps see better performance; and, I know how to move my Standard tier app service to premium, to check and see what will improve.  I was not so clear on the pitfalls/challenges of moving the premium tier BACK to the standard tier, after several hours.  I seem to remember some trouble spots, but I'm wondering if I am avoiding these problems if I already began in a working standard tier.  Any insights from app devs who have seen these types of apps moving up/down in pricing would be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure, specifically, what issues you're referring to. But the only specific thing you have to work around is total storage space available, if you downsize.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to this question is no there are no pitfalls unless you're using too many slots(more than 5 I believe, scaled out beyond 10 instances or using more storage than standard supports.

However there are a couple of things I want to quickly point out. If you're simply moving up to premium you won't likely see any improvments unless you plan to scale out to more than 10 instances or more storage is needed. Premium as it is in GA currently use the same VM's as standard.

If you move up to Premium V2 however you should see a different. These use D series VM's rather than A series so it should be a bit of a spec bump over standard. This is not GA however and isn't currently easy to scale to due to it's limited availability.

Hree is some more info on Premium V2: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-app-service-premium-v2-in-public-preview/

Comment: Thanks, much. I’ve got to try those V2 instances.